# How can I scroll the view of a zoomed in emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I use the plus/minus buttons on the lower right corner of Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1, I get bigger/smaller emulator view. But once I have zoomed in, how can I scroll the view? It always goes to the top left corner and I can't seem to scroll it, as touches and drag gestures simply reflect as gestures on the emulated device.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Android Studio because this feature used to work in the previous version. I've filed an issue with Google.